# CUBEFUNCTIONS failing in Excel Services but ok in Excel

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services

I'm encountering a problem whereby we have Excel reports that are saved on our `SharePoint` server:

- when opened in `Excel Services` they show `#N/A`.
- if I then hit the button `OPEN IN EXCEL` the formulas update fine in the local version of Excel.

The formulas use Excel's `CUBEFUNCTIONS`. Seems like pivot tables are fine but these `CUBEFUNCTIONS` are rather brittle.

As a temporary measure I will force the files in the doc library to open in the client application.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem before?

Comment: Are other values based on the data connection working?  The cube functions listed here should work in the Excel Web App: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/cube-functions-reference-HA010342384.aspx.  If you are using something else, it may not work.

Comment: Hi John - I think that list is pretty much all the CUBE* functions - are there some not on that list? I'm using `Excel Services` rather than the `Excel Web App`

Comment: Trying to find a list of differences between the web app and the services themselves and don't see one.  I assume you have the same functionality in both the web app and in service, but not 100% sure.